Как вывести данные из JSON в приложение ReactJS
Подскажите, есть приложение, которое через запрос fethData получает ответ в формате json:
[
  {"name":"Игорь",  "znak":"Водолей"},
  {"name":"Андрей", "znak":"Стрелец"},
  {"name":"Максим", "znak":"Дева"}
]

Как в React правильно внести данные в переменную, а потом построить из красивое отображения с помощью .map?
Например:
fetch('https://example.ru/znaki.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(answer => {
        const result = answer;
        // оперируйте данными здесь сколько душе угодно
    });

const Otvet = result

const App = () => {
  return ( 
    <div> Otvet.name </div> 
    <div> Otvet.znak </div> 
  )
}

Не знаю, как это сделать с помощью map, только что бы, если пришло в json 5 человек, их всех надо вывести.

Как отрисовать список в reactjs

@SwaD спасибо, похоже на то что мне нужно, вечером попробую, отпишу)

@SwaD твой код работает если данные записаны, но когда я пытаюсь получить данные из fetchData и записываю их в переменную он перестает работать

Покажите полный код компонента. Если то что у вас в примере это так и релизовано, то вам надо менять архитектуру(условно). fetch положить в useEffect компонента и результат записывать в переменную состояния.

Разобрался нужно было ещё почитать документацию по React.DOM, твоя статья сгодилась)

Опубликуйте свой ответ, как вы решили вашу пробелму. Возможно, другим посетителям это будет полезно
